# How could I print out Javascript to an Apache 2 log file?

Tags: javascript, logging, apache2

So today I'm trying to do something incredibly mundane, but can't seem to find the right answer anywhere.

I just want to print out a statement to my Apache 2 log file.

I have php and perl working beautifully, but can't seem to figure out the correct statement for Javascript (.js)

I'm honestly not even sure if I need any modules for the task either. Any assistance would be rad.

Obviously I can get a little output in my web browser, but it would be really helpful to get an output in sequence in my log file, just to get a better visualization of how everything is working together.

Is there any way to pipe that web browser output back and written to my log file?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the JavaScript? Apache doesn't generally run JS directly, but might run a reverse proxy to a server running on Node.js. Are you talking about client-side JS which runs on the user's browser and not on the server?

Comment: Hey Quentin, yeah, I was wondering if there is a way to pipe the output browser side to my personal Apache log file. Note, this would just be for my personal docker environment for testing purposes.